# Need help to understand behaviour of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

Let's say I have a person class and equality is based on `id` attribute. Below is the implementation of `Person` class -

```
class Person {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;

    public Person(int id, String firstName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((Person) obj).getId() == this.id;
    }
}
```

I am using `Person` class as as key of a HashMap. Now see below code -

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person1 = new Person(1, "Person 1");
        Person person2 = new Person(2, "Person 2");

        HashMap<Person, String> testMap = new HashMap<Person, String>();
        testMap.put(person1, "Person 1");
        testMap.put(person2, "Person 2");

        person1.setId(2);

        System.out.println(testMap.get(person1));
        System.out.println(testMap.get(person2));

    }
}
```

Notice, though we have added two different person object as key to the HashMap, later we have changed the `id` of `person1` object to 2 to make both the person object equal.

Now, I am getting output as -

```
Person 2
Person 2
```

I can see there are two key-value pairs in the HashMap with data: "person1/Person 1" and "person2/Person 2", still I will always get "Person 2" as output and I can never access value "Person 1". Also notice, we have duplicate key in HashMap.

I can understand the behavior after looking at the source code, but doesn't it seem to be problem? Can we take some precaution to prevent it?

Comment: you map is using a weird key, what is the goal you are trying to achieve with the map?

Comment: Refer Below link for understand " How HashMap work internally:     http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/how-hashmap-works-in-java/

Comment: @RC Yeah, I know it's weird. I did it intentionally for testing purpose. Also, I don't know what's the problem with this question. It's not always possible to identify it's a duplicate question. I am assuming this is the reason for down vote.

Comment: I don't know either why you were downvoted (I don't think it's because of the duplicate, though) I counter balanced the downvote :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how `hashCode()` value is used by `HashMap`.

While it is required that two equal objects of same hash code, reverse is not necessarily true.  Two unequal objects can have same hash code (as `int` has only finite set of possible values).

Everytime you put an object in `HashMap`, it stores the object in a bucket identified by key's `hashCode()`.  So, based on how `hashCode()` is implemented, you should have a fair distribution of entries in various buckets.

Now, when you try to retrieve a value, the `HashMap` will identify the bucket in which given `key` falls, and then will iterate through all keys in that bucket to pick the entry for given key - in this stage it will use `equals()` method to identify the entry.

In your case, `person1` is sitting in `bucket 1` and `person2` is sitting in `bucket 2`.

However, when you changed the `hashCode()` value of `person1` by updating its `id`, the `HashMap` is unaware of this change.  Later, when you look up an entry using `person1` as key, the `HashMap` thinks that it should be present in `bucket 2` (as `person1.hashCode()` is `2` now), and after that when it iterates `bucket 2` using `equals` method, it finds an entry of `person2` and thinks that it is the object that you are interested in as `equals` in your case too is based on `id` attribute.

Above explanation is evident when one looks at [implementation of `HashMap#get`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java/?v=source) method as shown below:

```
public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**PS** Sometimes when you know an answer to question, you forget to lookup for duplicate questions, and jump right into answering the question before anyone can reply - that's what happened in this case.  Should be careful next time :-)

Comment: So, should we make key immutable always or what would you suggest?

Comment: Yes, ideally it should be immuatable

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `equals()` method uses the hashcode only. You should be comparing all your person fields like `firstName`.

Comment: Agree, I did it intentionally. My question is, don't we have an inaccessible key-value pair in the HashMap which we can never be accessed? Also in the example, we set the id to 3, we will get `null` as value.